# Error instantiating servlet class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, servlet-dispatching

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

`Message Error instantiating servlet class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]`

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1412)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1220)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.80
```

I have seen all solution of this question and implements them but my problem haven't solve

Comment: just add a simple reproducible example.

Comment: How does your app include `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`?